# peewee problem: No module named 'playhouse' when deploying using AWS Chalice

Tags: peewee, chalice

I am working on an [AWS Chalice](https://aws.github.io/chalice/quickstart.html#deploying) project, and I chose peewee as the ORM for the DB we have.

When I run things locally with `chalice local` I can run my api with no problem, I'm able to CRUD normally.

When I deploy my microservice using `chalice deploy` and I go test it out on the live url, I encounter an error 500. When looking into the logs I see this message multiple times:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-01-03 22:39:57.665000 s98frt [ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'playhouse'
```

I cannot do `poetry add playhouse`, because I get the following error: `Could not find a matching version of package playhouse`. Strange because playhouse comes with peewee.

What can you suggest me to do to fix this?

Thank you so much

Comment: `playhouse` is a part of the peewee package, see https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/blob/master/setup.py#L145-L146 -- if you `pip install peewee` then playhouse is already installed.

Comment: @coleifer Thanks for pointing that out. I didn't realize from reading the docs. Would it be appropriate to mention it there, or is it a common pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your requirements.txt and make sure it has ==ver.
ex:

```
peewee==3.17.1
```